# How to verify JWT signature manually in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an Asp Net Core API without any controller implementation. Client (Auth0 implementation) is passing a JWT token (RS256 alg) that I need to verify if signature is valid or not. I have gone through the Auth0 official documentation that suggest to implement JwtBearer and set the app to UseAuthentication in startup configuration

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer

```
public class Startup
{
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddMvc();

    // 1. Add Authentication Services
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://myapi.auth0.com/";
        options.Audience = "API/Endpoint";
    });
}
```

As mentioned above, there is no controller in this API, I can't decorate the method with Authorize attrubute so I am left with the option of verifying this signature manually. For this reason, I have been through stack overflow posts where people have mentioned different approaches such as the use of

> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

while other have opposed to it and suggested to use low level implementation etc. I have tried couple but no success so far.

Let's say following method is the entry point of the API that receives the JWT token. Would please someone tell me what I need to do in order to verify the signature manually

```
    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var accessToken = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        // Here I wan't to verify the signature?
        // This token has RS256 alg
    }
```

Following is the JWT decoded result

[image]

Comment: Can you try changing `services.AddMvc();` to `services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();

                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });` because that will remove the requirement for the authorize attribute

Comment: @p3tch, I don't see it making any difference. Doesn't matter if there is a token or not, InvokeAsync method still getting the hit and serving the request. By the way the code you suggested, isn't it to verify the policies (Claims/roles etc.) while I just want to verify if the signature is valid?

Comment: Yeah, you're right - your middleware will still be hit before the auth middleware even if you do this - my mistake

Comment: This one looks promising https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/manually-validating-rs256-jwt-dotnet/ (while I still think it should be possible to use the "normal" middleware)

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this:

```
public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var accessToken = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    var secretKey = "Insert your secret key here";

    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));
        // Add any other validations: issuer, audience, lifetime, etc
    }

    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var principal = handler.ValidateToken(accessToken, validationParameters, out var validToken);
    JwtSecurityToken validJwt = validToken as JwtSecurityToken;

    if (validJwt == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid JWT");
    }

    if (!validJwt.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Algorithm must be RS256");
    }

    // Add any validations which cannot be included into TokenValidationParameters

    // Validation passed, continue with your logic
}
```

It is based on [this article](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core), which explains how to validate jwt tokens received through cookies. Although the objective is different from yours, the way of validating tokens can be applied to your problem.

Comment: For instance, what might the content of `secretKey` be? I have an endpoint in my issuer that provides this key, but I'm unsure which part of the JSON available there should be passed to the constructor of `SymmetricSecurityKey`.